# Detecting Data Changes with Change Handlers

Tags: lightning-aura-components, if, aura-handler

I am [looking at this example in the Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_data_change.htm), and I can't replicate this in my instance. What am I doing wrong? Here is a snippet.

```
<!-- Lookup Attributes -->
<aura:attribute name="selectedContactLookupRecord" type="sObject" default="{}"/>    

<!-- Handlers -->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.selectedContactLookupRecord}" action="{!c.relDivisions}" />

<div class="slds-form-element">
    <c:customLookup objectAPIName="contact" IconName="standard:contact" label="Lead Inventor" selectedRecord="{!v.selectedContactLookupRecord}"/>
</div>
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.selectedContactLookupRecord))}">
        //Stuff
    <aura:if />
</div>
```

Controller:

```
relDivisions : function(component, event) {
    console.log("relDivisions is starting up...")
    //additional code
```

I *KNOW* v.selectedContactLookupRecord is getting populated because the aura:if is functioning correctly. But why can't I even get the console.log to fire off?

Comment: The document says that - automatically invoke a change handler, which is a client-side controller action, when a value in one of the component's attributes changes. Were you expecting the action handler to run on load of the component. If so, I think it runs only if the selectedContactLookupRecord value changes

Comment: are you passing selectedContactLookupRecord value from outside component?

Comment: I am setting the attribute with a lookup, so I am expecting the action handler to run when I select a contact. The aura:if statement is working perfectly fine and only showing the additional //Stuff when selectedContactLookupRecord has been selected and the value changes.